# Can't verify method called inside Select() using Moq framework

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, moq, verify

I have a problem with verifying that certain method was called on mock inside LINQ Select() query.

Here is the method of ContentManager I want to test:

```
public string ProcessElements(List<Item> items)
{
    var processed = items.Select(item => item.Process(Constants.Text));

    return Serialize(processed);
}
```

I want to test that Process() is called for elements of the list. My test method looks like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ProcessItems_ValidItems_ProcessCalled()
{
    var contentManager = new ContentManager();
    var itemMock = new Mock<Item>();
    itemMock.Setup(m => m.Process(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns("serialized");

    contentManager.ProcessElements(new List<Item>() { itemMock.Object });

    itemMock.Verify(m => m.Process(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once());
}
```

When I run this test it fails and returns the following message:

> Test method ProcessItems_ValidItems_ProcessCalled threw exception:
>
> Moq.MockException:
>
> Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed:
>
> m => m.Process(It.IsAny())
>
> No setups configured.
>
> No invocations performed.

**But** if I change Select() to foreach, then test passes successfully:

```
public string ProcessElements(List<Item> iitem)
{
    var processed = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in iitem)
    {
        processed.Add(item.Process(Constants.Text));
    }

    return Serialize(processed);
}
```

What is wrong with Moq + Select()? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure what `.Serialize` method does but `.Select` doesn't run the actual query it only returns an object that knows how to iterate through `IEnumerable<T>`.

With multiple LINQ methods like `.Where`, `.Select` you can build the query that will be lazily iterated later usually by `foreach` or a call to `.ToList`, `.ToDictionary` etc.

So to run the LINQ query change it from:

`.Select(...)`

TO:

`.Select(...).ToList()`

Comment: @AlonJacobson Thank you very much! My fault that I forgot about lazy initialization.